# Problema al capturar una hora en el timepicker

Tags: android, android-studio, datetime

Poseo un `fragment` el cual debera guardar una hora, luego de realizar todo el codigo simplemente me genera error al momento de ejecutarlo

**SelectordeAlarmas.java** (`fragment` que capturara las alarmas)

```
package company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.Perfil;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import company.viral.organizadorjec.ActivitysPrincipales.MainActivity;
import company.viral.organizadorjec.R;


public class SelectordeAlarmas extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //creamos la vista del fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selector_alarma, container, false);

        final AlarmManager alarma;
        //cramos las variables del layout
        Button acepalarm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaceptaralarma);
        Button boralarm = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnborraralarma);
        Button cancelar = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btncancelaralarma);
        //los TV
        final TextView alarmview = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.avisoalarm);
        //alarma
        final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);


        //instanciamos la alarma
        alarma=(AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        //necesitamos un calendar para la seleccion de tiempo

        final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();

        //implementar el metodo de aceptar alarma y cambiar aviso
        acepalarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker.getHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,timePicker.getMinute());

                int hora=timePicker.getHour();
                int minuto=timePicker.getMinute();

                alarmview.setText("La alarma esta a "+hora+":"+minuto);
            }
        });



        //implementamos el motodo del boton de cerrar sesion
        cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //establecemos un mensaje de alerta para la confirmacion
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("¿Desea cerrar sesion?");
                builder.setTitle("Alerta!");
                builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    //de ser positivo vamos al inicio y cerramo
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent i= new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

**selector_alarma.xml** (xml del fragment)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.Perfil.SelectordeAlarmas">>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">


            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Seleccione su alarma."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />


            <TimePicker
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/timePicker" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Alarma no establecida."
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/avisoalarm"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                tools:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="35dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:text="Aceptar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                    android:id="@+id/btnaceptaralarma"
                    android:onClick="onClickAceptarR" />
                <Button
                    android:text="Borrar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
                    android:id="@+id/btnborraralarma"
                    android:onClick="onClickAceptarR" />

                <Button
                    android:text="Cancelar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/btncancelaralarma"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="onClickRegresar"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.Button" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es para una agenda... por los momentos solo quiero que la hora seleccionada se establezca en el `TextView` que dice "alarma no establecida"

y simplemente al acceder al `fragment` me sale esto en el `logcat`

```
01-28 14:40:50.817 1717-1717/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.finsky.hygiene.HygieneJobService', referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.dailyhygiene.DailyHygiene.a
01-28 14:40:50.828 1717-1717/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.finsky.services.MaintenanceWindowJobService', referenced from method com.google.android.finsky.dailyhygiene.DailyHygiene.g
01-28 14:40:51.552 1717-1717/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(847): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, resolution=null, message=null}
01-28 14:40:58.950 1500-1500/company.viral.organizadorjec E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: company.viral.organizadorjec, PID: 1500
                                                                            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.icu.util.Calendar
                                                                                at company.viral.organizadorjec.FragmentMenu.Perfil.SelectordeAlarmas.onCreateView(SelectordeAlarmas.java:46)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                                at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 14:44:11.338 3616-3616/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-28 14:44:11.639 3616-3616/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-28 14:44:11.639 3616-3616/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-28 14:46:00.524 153-776/? E/AudioMTKHardware: setCommonParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=off"
01-28 14:56:31.430 806-806/? E/RemoteViews: ANR Warning,RemoteViews can only be used once ,if not ,it may cause ANR in hosts such as Laucher,SystemUI. keys for search <ANR Exception MSG   History>
01-28 14:57:25.630 806-806/? E/Sensors: new acc setDelay handle(0),ns(66667000) err! go to hwmsen
01-28 14:57:25.880 153-25479/? E/AudioMTKHardware: setCommonParameters() still have param.size() = 1, remain param = "screen_state=on"
```

Comment: Hola Erny que tal apenas contesto hoy un día de mucho trabajo, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error principal es:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.icu.util.Calendar

Usa:

```
    import java.util.Calendar;
...
...
final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
```

En lugar de :

`import android.icu.util.Calendar`;